# Plugin to set all Posts in a certain Category to a certain Post Format

Tags: plugins, categories, post-formats, automation

I want to setup my WordPress so that whenever I create a post with the category "Tweet", my wordpress installation automatically changes the post format from post to aside. This will help me because I want to use my wordpress for posting longer than 140 tweets to my twitter feed. The posting to twitter has been setup and it works.

The problem is that the Wordpress iOS app doesn't allow me to change the post format to Aside, so the only thing I can do is set the category of the post to "Tweet" and as soon as my wordpress receives it, it changes the post to aside.

I found the plugin "Set Aside" but it lets me change the post formats for all posts of a certain category that have already been posted, not the ones that I will post in the future.

Is this possible?

Comment: I edited your question.  I am assuming you mean post format not post type.

Comment: Hey Chris, yes, I meant post format. I am not fully versed with the terminology... Just looking for answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this plugin in your `wp-content/plugins` folder and then activate it:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: WPSE53245 - Set Tweet category posts as Aside
Plugin URI: http://http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53235
Description: Set Tweet category posts as Aside
Version: 0.1
Author: Ashfame
Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1521/ashfame
*/

    add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse53235_set_post_format_aside' );

    function wpse53235_set_post_format_aside( $postID ) {
        if ( has_post_format( 'aside', $postID ) || !has_term( 'tweet', 'category', $postID ) )
            return;
        set_post_format( $postID, 'aside' );
    }
```

Comment: Added return statement for conditional check not in 'tweet' category or if post format has already been set.

Comment: Ashfame, thanks for the answer, but if you read my post properly, the reason why I'm asking specifically for a plugin is because I want to use the iOS wordpress app to post the aside. That will supersede the functions in the theme, will it not? 

I've written an explanatory post about my setup here -> http://blog.nitinkhanna.com/long-tweets-from-wordpress/

Comment: @Chris_O Thanks! I forgot about the condition while posting the answer

Comment: @NitinKhanna Did you try it? It should work. Because that app will use XMLRPC to publish the post on your WordPress, IMO.

Comment: @Ashfame just one question before I try it... The category name that you've used is 'tweet' right? Because actually, the category name that I've used is LongTweet and it's slug is long-tweet. So I just need to replace the !has_term('tweet'...) with !has_term('LongTweet'...) right?

Comment: Also, is there a significance to using wpse53235 in the function name or is that just to randomize the name?

Comment: @NitinKhanna Don't hesitate to try, nothing is gonna blow up :P Go ahead, it works for name/slug/id.

Comment: @Ashfame thanks a lot! Your solution seems to have worked partially. When I saved a post from within wordpress from the browser, the post automatically changed to an aside. But when I saved a post from the iOS app, it did not save as an aside. So, I deleted it from the web browser. As soon as I deleted it, it showed up as an aside in the trash. So I undeleted it and it came back in my published list as an aside. Obviously this means that the post has to go through the theme once before it is changed to an aside.

Comment: @NitinKhanna My bad! Try this plugin

Comment: @Ashfame... What plugin? You're about to give me a link?

Comment: @NitinKhanna Check the answer, I modified the code to be used as a plugin