# Assign post format to categories

Tags: plugins, categories, post-formats, automation

I'm looking for a way to allow Wordpress (via a plugin?) to assign a specific post format to categories. (I can assign categories via a third party like IFTTT)

Then all my posts in a certain category will be formatted rather than just text posts.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this answer: [Plugin to set all Posts in a certain Category to a certain Post Format](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/plugin-to-set-all-posts-in-a-certain-category-to-a-certain-post-format) which provides a way to do this by hard-coding it into your theme.

This should allow you to assign post formats to a certain category.  You could also go the route of adding a categories button to a specific post format.